# Check files exist in a directory

Tags: java, java-8

I want to read files in a folder using Java. Unfortunately sometimes the files are missing and I get NPE.

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> getCPUTemp() throws IOException
    {
        File directory = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/thermal");

        if (directory.exists())
        {
            HashMap<String, Integer> usageData = new HashMap<>();

            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

            for (File file : fList)
            {
                if (file.isDirectory() && file.getName().startsWith("thermal_zone"))
                {
                    ......................
                }
            }
            return usageData;
        }
        return null;
```

How can I prevent this and return `null` if the files are not there? Can you show me a solution with Java 8?

Comment: Anything wrong with returning an empty hashmap instead of null: return new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Comment: I need to return only null of files does not exists.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NPE? Could you check with `file.exists()`?

Comment: I get NPE here `File[] fList = directory.listFiles();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get NPE here for (File file : fList)

It should be that the `fList` is null.

So, right after the `fList` creation, check null.

```
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
if (fList == null) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: My mistake. I get NPE here `for (File file : fList)`

Comment: Ok, I modified my answer.